# Page Not Always Detecting when Image is Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Ruby on Rails app that uses Twitter Bootstrap.

On a page, there is a carousel that uses large images. Because on this, I show a loading GIF on the page until all the images are loaded.

So, initially, there is the GIF

```
<div id="loading-div" class="centered">
    <img src="<%= asset_path("page-loader.gif") %>" />
</div>
```

And after the page is loaded, we hide the carousel, wait for one of the images to load, then hide the GIF and show the carousel. But **sometimes**, the onload event is called. E.g. when I've already visited the page and I navigate somewhere else then navigate again to the carousel page.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$('#home-carousel').hide();
$('#first-image').load(function(){
    $('#loading-div').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#home-carousel').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Is there anyway to recheck if the image is already loaded? And if so, don't display the GIF?

Is it possible that the image is loaded before the "onload" and "hide()" are set for the carousel and image?

What's the best way to handle this kind of scenario?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use typical image preloading. `var img = new Image(); $(img).on('load', function () {...}); img.src = 'thesrc.jpg';`

Comment: I'm not completely sure if the problem went away, but it hasn't happened again yet. Thanks much! I like this method!